# alias keyword (like typedef) in C#?

Tags: c#

I have 2 libs that have different case on different platforms :(. It seems like everything else is the same (method names, param order, etc). How can i create an alias so my current spelling for platform a will work when i compile for platform b (I would really hate to make a wrapper for case difference)

Comment: Can you give (simplified) code for what you mean? Most likely there is a better way to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I alias a class name in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244246/how-do-i-alias-a-class-name-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the using keyword to create an alias:

```
using MyName = YourNamespace.YourSubNamespace.YourType;
```

You could then conditionally include the aliases using a #if directive.  However you would need to do this at the top of every source file: there's no #include-like directive to allow you to create a file of aliases and import them into each source file.  So if you are planning on doing this in for a large codebase then it may be worth considering another approach such as the wrapper approach.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, you can create an alias for a [namespace or a type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423(VS.80).aspx).  It's not quite as flexible as typedef, but it might make it possible for you to alias the type in your lib a to have the lowercase (or uppercase or whatever) like you want to do.