# C# typedef/alias like construct on static types

Tags: c#

Suppose I have some relatively complex generic object that could be simplified as

```
class A<T>
{
   static void foo(T x) { }
}
```

To use foo, one must repeatedly use the class name with the generic.

```
A<MyLongTypeNameIsNotFunToType>.foo(x);
```

It would be very nice if it was possible to simplify this:

```
alias AA = A<MyLongTypeNameIsNotFunToType>;
AA.foo(x);
```

Only thing I can think of is to create a wrapper class

```
class B : A<MyLongTypeNameIsNotFunToType> { }
```

which allows me to access A's static members through B. One problem is that this requires a public constructor, which, in my case, is not possible. Obviously I could wrap A's static members in B but that seems highly redundant.

[I tried using, but note that I need to access the static members so I need the static type. Using doesn't seem to work with static types.
error: ___ is a type which isn't valid in the given context]

Any elegant solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [alias keyword (like typedef) in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844651/alias-keyword-like-typedef-in-c)

Comment: @Jannik No. Seems people are not paying attention to the *static* part of the question.

Comment: "but note that I need to access the static members so I need the static type" -> you can still use "using". I wonder where this doesn't work? This does seem to be a dupe so I'm deleting my answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

To make an alias of a Type you do the following where your namespaces are specified

```
using S = MyLongTypeNameIsNotFunToType;
```

Then to use it you can do the following

```
//A<S>.foo(new S());
A<S>.foo(x);
```

You can also continue to change A to the following

```
using S = MyLongTypeNameIsNotFunToType;
using AA = A<MyLongTypeNameIsNotFunToType>;
```

And then in your code you can go and do

```
AA.foo(x);
```

Or

```
A<S>.foo(x);
```

Here is a copy and paste into a console application sample

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    using B = MyLongTypeNotFunToType;
    using C = A<MyLongTypeNotFunToType>;
    public class A<T>
    {
        public static void foo(T foo)
        {

        }
    }

    public class MyLongTypeNotFunToType
    {

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          var x = new B();
          A<B>.foo(x);
          C.foo(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two solutions:

1. use `using` in the class file as all others have mentioned..

Class definition:

```
class A<T>
{
    public static void foo(T x) { }
}
```

Usage:

```
using Alias = A<MyLongTypeNameIsNotFunToType>;

public class Dummy
{
    public Dummy(MyLongTypeNameIsNotFunToType x)
    {
        Alias.foo(x);
    }
}
```

2. Define the class `A` in different way such that type `T` is resolved implicitly meaning type of parameter `x` will resolve type `T` automatically (at compile-time).

My reason for going with this option will be that you have `static` method otherwise you can implement class `A<T>` same way as `List<T>` and use the solution 1 given above.

Class definition:

```
class A // <-- removed the <T> from class and added in the method declaration
{
    public static void foo<T>(T x) { }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Dummy
{
    public Dummy(MyLongTypeNameIsNotFunToType x)
    {
        A.foo(x);
    }
}
```

I hope you see the simplicity in the solution 2.

Answer (score -1):

Use `using` to alias your type or namespace.

```
using   identifier = namespace-or-type-name;
```

So you can do this.

```
using LongType = A<MyLongTypeNameIsNotFunToType>;
```

You can read more about usage and details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765(v=vs.71).aspx)

**Update :**

***It would be very nice if it was possible to simplify this:***

> alias AA = A<MyLongTypeNameIsNotFunToType>;
>   AA.foo(x);

Yes, you can achieve this with below code.

```
using newname = A<int> ;
newname.foo(10);
```

Check the [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aJyBwG)