# How to create a custom type for Expression<Func<T1, T2>>?

Tags: c#

I frequently use a navigation properties, that look like this:

```cs
Expression<Func<TItem, TProperty>> NavigationProperty { get; set; }
```

I wonder if it's possible to create a custom type that I will be able to use instead of the full expression definition, something like a delegate but for `Expression<Func<T1, T2>>`

Concept:

```cs
class NavigationExpression<T1, T2> : Expression<Func<T1, T2>> {} 
// The error: 'NavigationExpression<T1, T2>': cannot derive from sealed type 'Expression<Func<T1, T2>>'
```

So then I can use it:

```cs
NavigationProperty<Person, string> getName = p => p.Name;
```

If it's impossible to implement, why is that? What is it that I don't understand?

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"? Do you get any error messages? Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Comment: why do you want to create custom expressions?

Comment: @Progman I added the error to the initial question

Comment: @DanielA.White Laziness. I don't want to write `Expression<Func<TItem, TProperty>>` every time. Also it would look cleaner I guess

Comment: The generic lambda expression class is sealed, so this is a non starter.

Comment: @GeorgeKarlinzer Is using an alias an option? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257989/defining-type-aliases

Comment: @Progman You cannot have an open generic alias, the generic type arguments must be resolved when the alias is defined.