# what is advantage of using conditional attribute over #if/#endif

Tags: c#, .net, conditional-compilation

I would really like to know is there any real advantage of using conditional attriubtes over #if and #endif. For me, using anyone is same apart from the syntax difference.

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public void CheckState()
{

}
```

I found  a similar link but does not give much information.

[C# !Conditional attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230191/c-sharp-conditional-attribute).

Also, read in a book (dont want to mention book name) conditional attribute generates more efficient IL code a and hence it should be used. But i couldn't get enough proof of this statement or example.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788605/if-debug-vs-conditionaldebug

Comment: Have you read answer provided by Jon Skeet to that question you linked? It explains it quite well.