# Use the WPF toolkit messagebox using custom name

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I am using the WPF toolkit messagebox now using something like this

```
Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show(MessageCenter.Show(12131011, true));
```

Then i did this

```
 Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox Mebox=new  Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox();
```

Surprise.Doesn't work.

What i am trying to do is use create a new Messagebox named Mebox which is basically a renamed version of `Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox` since typing `Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox` is tedious.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I alias a class name in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244246/c-alias-a-class-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried including the namespace and or giving it an Alias.

At the top of the cs file put this:

```
using MeBox = Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox;
```