# C# paste T model class dynamically as variable

Tags: c#, class, dynamic, declare

I want to store my model class as a variable and use it in all my code dynamically. For example I have something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Student> students = GetAllStudents();
```

Normally I must always declare and retype Student class. But I need to declare it only once and after that use it dynamically in my code. Simply I want to do something like this:

```
Student dynamicType;
```

So after that can be possible:

```
IEnumerable<dynamicType> students = GetAllStudents();
```

Can you help me to find right solution? Is it possible to do something like this?
Thank you

Comment: what is the problem using direct `Student` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I alias a class name in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244246/how-do-i-alias-a-class-name-in-c)

Comment: @Mostafiz Because I want to declare it only once..... I have function in my controller and it starts with declaration:

`IEnumerable<Student> students = GetAllStudents();`

But after that Im calling few generic methods example:

`students = iQueryableStudents.Where(MyGenericFunction<Student>(something, something));`

With Type Alias mentioned by StriplingWarrior I can use alias and if I need to change class and aply my code somewhere else and I can change only alias (only on one place).
Or do you think that this is bad idea?

Comment: @Gilad Green Im not sure, because before the answer from StriplingWarrior, I was not able to understand How do I alias a class name in C#? topic and find my answer in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "dynamic".

If you just don't want to use the class name "Students", then you're looking for a Type Alias.

```
using dynamicType = MyNameSpace.Student;

...
IEnumerable<dynamicType> students = GetAllStudents();
```

If you want to be able to specify which type you're dealing with from another part of code, you're looking for Generics.

```
void DoSomething<T>()
{
    IEnumerable<T> things = GetAllThings<T>();
    ...
}

...
DoSomething<Student>();
```

If you want to be able to interact with the class without having any specific type associated with it, you're looking for the `dynamic` keyword.

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> students = GetAllStudents();
foreach(var student in students)
{
    dynamic studentFoo = student.foo; // no type checking
}
```

If you want to avoid typing "Student" everywhere, but you really do want the items in your IEnumerable to be statically-checked `Student`s, then you may just want to use the `var` keyword.\

```
var students = GetAllStudents();
```

Comment: Thank you so much StriplingWarrior!

"If you just don't want to use the class name "Students", then you're looking for a Type Alias.

using dynamicType = MyNameSpace.Student;

...
IEnumerable<dynamicType> students = GetAllStudents();"

This was right answer for me :-)